# Select where joined table has the more listed values

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables :

```
A: id, name
B: id, name
C: id_A, id_B
```

The relation is A has many B.
There is another table with the relation has many B.

What I would like to do is find the A that has the most B.id I listed.
Something like

```
SELECT * FROM A JOIN C ON A.id=C.id_A JOIN B ON B.id=C.id_B WHERE B.ID HAVE_MOST(5,22,39,110,235);
```

It will return the first A that have all the values and if it's not found, it will return the first A that have a combination of 4 of those values, etc.

Is this possible in mysql ?

Comment: Can you please provide [some sample data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the job :

```
SELECT *, count(A.id) as number FROM A JOIN C ON A.id=C.id_A JOIN B ON B.id=C.id_B WHERE B.ID IN (5,22,39,110,235) GROUP BY A.id ORDER BY number DESC LIMIT 1
```